# Jetpack Compose and DI with Dagger 2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-2

Recently I was working on a small project and thought of one thing about compose and dagger.

Usually I used Dagger with inject function that was dong everything for me but now it seems that it isn't work that way because we don't have any "object" to inject into. So my question is how to inject now? I can still create components like before but it seems that i need to provide properties by myself or create some @Composable functions that will do it for me.

So my question is how to work with DI (especially with Dagger) and Compose now?

I was looking for some articles but most are about hilt and I want to use pure dagger.

Comment: Compose still needs Activity, that's your entry point.

Comment: @TheLibrarian yeah I know, but if I create all subcomponents in one activity and do nkt separate them then what's tge point of scopes? I mean I can create all viewmodels and repositories in my activity and then just pass them as arguments but I want to make viewmodel when I need it and remove when I dont. That's the question

Comment: I understand and I knew where you were headed but the thing is Dagger does not offer you this directly - you have to do those things manually. The point wasn't that you have everything in the scope of activity but rather have multiple scopes handled in the activity (The cost of that usually makes switching to Hilt seem like a better choice). [NOT MINE but here is a quick hint on how to do that](https://proandroiddev.com/dagger-2-and-jetpack-compose-integration-8a8d424ffdb4)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.